# "is" or "are" with "fewer"?

Tags: grammatical-number, countable-nouns

Which one is correct? (Or is neither?)

> This field can contain 30 characters, fewer is recommended.
>
> This field can contain 30 characters, fewer are recommended.

Comment: This field can contain 30 characters; using fewer is recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"...fewer are" is correct.

In the example,  "character" is a Count Noun.